# Can't run rake task requiring 'nokogiri'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, nokogiri

We have a rake task running a complex conversion between database systems. We've upgraded the task, which now required Nokogiri. It's installed:

```
`gem list --local`:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...
nokogiri (1.5.9)
...
```

Ruby is in 1.8.x version, requiring a `require 'rubygems'`:

```
`ruby -v`
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x8770 on patchlevel 358) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
```

With irb, everything seems fine:

```
`irb`
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

However, starting the rake task, it doesn't seem to find nokogiri:

```
lib/tasks$ RAILS_ENV="test" rake redmine::migrate_from_buggy_new.rake 280 --trace
(in /var/www/redmine)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- nokogiri
/var/www/redmine/lib/tasks/migrate_from_buggy_new.rake:27:in `require'
/var/www/redmine/lib/tasks/migrate_from_buggy_new.rake:27
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/redmine/Rakefile:7
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

I'm not sure what to do next, I'm fresh in the Ruby environment and everything is still strange and new.

Edit: The beginning of the rake file looks like this:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'action_controller'
require 'iconv'
require 'pp'

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

namespace :redmine do
  desc 'Buggy migration script'
  task :migrate_from_buggy => :environment do
```

Edit 2: Nokogiri is installed to `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri`. I've tried to include it into the search path, like this:

```
RAILS_ENV="test" rake redmine::migrate_from_buggy_new.rake 280 -I "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/"
RAILS_ENV="test" rake redmine::migrate_from_buggy_new.rake 280 -I "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9"
RAILS_ENV="test" rake redmine::migrate_from_buggy_new.rake 280 -I "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib"
RAILS_ENV="test" rake redmine::migrate_from_buggy_new.rake 280 -I "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri"
```

All to no avail (same problem/error message).

Comment: What does the rake task look like? Did you `require "rubygems"` in it?

Comment: Updated the question with the beginning of the rake file, though I don't really see the significance.

Comment: If you need to `require 'rubygems'` it would have to occur at the top of your gem require list, not midway down. Ruby 1.8.7 was the first that did NOT need you to require ruby gems; Try starting irb and entering `require 'rubygems'` and you should see a `false` result, meaning it's already loaded. That won't fix the problem but will remove some confusion.

Comment: As you can see in my post, `require 'rubygems'` in irb says `true`. I've also moved the `require 'rubygems'` to the first non-comment statement in the rake script, with no discernable difference to before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: if it's at all feasible for your environment, consider using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It has a tendency to make a lot of these nightmarish gem issues go away.